# Dynamically generate input fields on the basis of Changing number value at runtime using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, runtime, input-field

I am woking on a PHP based form of a web project, I want to dynamically generate input select fields runtime on the basis of the value I put in my number input field.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
        <label>No. of Rooms: </label>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="3" name="roomno">
        <?php 
             

        ?>
</form>
```

Now I want to generate a select field for room type for each of the rooms at runtime with changing value of number field using PHP. Could anyone help me with the script?

Answer (score 0):

I think its rather a JavaScript solution and could look like this:

```html
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
        <label>No. of Rooms: </label>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="3" name="roomno" value="0" onchange="makeRoomTypeSelect(this)">
        <div id="roomtypes"></div>

</form>

<script>
    function makeRoomTypeSelect(input) {
        var html = '';

        for(i=1;i<=input.value;i++) {
            html = html + '<select name="room_type_' + i + '"><option value="type1">type 1</option><option value="type2">type 2</option><option value="type3">type 3</option></select>';
        }

        const element = document.getElementById('roomtypes');
        element.innerHTML = html;
    }
</script>
```